# Jackson ObjectMapper: Can java.util.Set be serialized to JSON array in ascending sorted order?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, set

I have a Java [`java.util.Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) of [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) types which I would like serialized to a JSON array in ascended sorted order.

There's an object mapper feature to serialize maps sorted by map keys, but nothing is said about java sets. If I store items in a `java.util.Set` in my POJO, will the Jackson `ObjectMapper` serialize them to the JSON array in any kind of order?

If not, I'm thinking of writing a custom serializer for the set for this purpose - is there a better way that someone can suggest?

---

Ultimately, the goal is to deserialize an array of unique integers into some sort of container in a "request" pojo. Then process the request and pass that input field into the corresponding output field (unchanged) in a "response" object.

I'd like to store the data in the POJOs as `java.util.Set<Integer>` just to keep all the users happy (if you try to store it as as subtype of `Set` then consumers of the POJO's interface may be upset that they can't just get a `Set` but have to expect a `HashSet` or a `TreeSet`).

Will this work?

1. JSON array `[5,4,3,2,1]` is deserialized into `Set<Integer>` BUT, I use `@JsonDeserialize(as=TreeSet.class)` on the setter method. So the runtime type of the object is now a `TreeSet` (even though it's stored in the POJO as a `Set`).
2. The `Set` is passed around through the server and ultimately ends being stored in the response POJO (runtime type is still `TreeSet`, even though the POJO field type is Set).
3. `ObjectMapper` serializes a `TreeSet` to JSON array `[1,2,3,4,5]` (because `TreeSet` is sorted naturally).

Item 3 above is the one I'm wondering about - will `ObjectMapper` use the runtime type of the POJO's field, or the declared type?

---

How can I ensure my `Set` is converted to a JSON array in sorted order?

Comment: Thanks @user - that article is about property order serialization. My question is about Set content order serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [JSON](http://www.json.org/) Array is an *ordered* collection, exactly like a Java array is:

> An *array* is an **ordered** collection of values. An array begins with `[` (left bracket) and ends with `]` (right bracket). Values are separated by `,` (comma).

However, *ordered* does not mean *sorted*. It just means that it retains the *order* of the given values:

- If the `Set` is sorted (e.g. `TreeSet`), then the JSON array is **sorted**, according to the sort order of the `Set`:

  > [**`TreeSet`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html): The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.
- If the `Set` is unordered (e.g. `HashSet`), then the JSON array is in the **arbitrary** order returned by the `Set`.

  > [**`HashSet`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html): It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

This is unlike the *fields* of a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) Object:

> An *object* is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs. An object begins with `{` (left brace) and ends with `}` (right brace). Each name is followed by `:` (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by `,` (comma).

Comment: Thanks - someone else suggested using a TreeSet at the same time. Sounds like a plan!

Answer (score 0):

A Jackson [`Converter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/Converter.html) can be created to order the `Set`, converting it to a `LinkedHashSet` with elements in the desired sort order.

```java
public class OrderedSetConverter 
        extends StdConverter<Set<Integer>, Set< Integer >> {
    @Override
    public Set<DayOfWeek> convert(Set<Integer> value) {
        return value == null ? null : value.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
    }
}

public class MyType {
    @JsonSerialize(converter = OrderedSetConverter.class)
    private Set<Integer> myValues;
}
```

When applied to a property using [`JsonSerialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html), the resulting JSON array will be in sorted order.  Additionally, this could be applied to a property using [`JsonDeserialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html), ensuring that the object resulting from reading JSON will have a `LinkedHashSet` with a sorted iteration order.

---

I used this approach in my project rather than using a `TreeSet` for a few reasons.  First, I wanted to accept `null` values in the set (mainly so that I could have use my standard null value handling deal with them with an appropriate API error message, rather than have a `NullPointerException` occur when creating the `TreeSet`.  Secondly, `TreeSet` changes the semantics of the set from the standard set contract, using the `Comparable` object's `compareTo` method to determine whether two objects are equal, rather than `Objevt.equals()`.  Finally, I wanted my clients of the Java API to be able to use any valid `Set` type that made sense for their applications, rather than being restricted to `TreeSet`.